# CSS Inheritance Problems

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Okay, I am trying to achieve for all of my elements to be 10px over from the left side of the screen except for the black box surrounding the other elements. I have set the margin and padding at 0px so that the black box can touch the edges of the screen. However, in doing so all elements inherit this value (to touch the left side of the screen) in which I would have to individually set margin and padding to every new element I create. I have tried setting the body tag to have 10px over from the left which pushes all elements over to the left and leaves 10px of white space on the left. When I have done so, this also makes it so that I cannot push the box back to touch the edge of the screen. In short - is there a way that I can make all of my elements inherit 10px to the left of the screen except for the box surrounding the elements.

```
body{
    display:flex;
    display: block;
    font-family: sheepman, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#boxcolor{
margin-left:-10px;
background-color:black;
}

#header{
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;

}


h1{
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 50px;
    margin:0px;
    padding-left:10px;


}

.Phead{
    color:white;
    padding-left:10px;
}

</style>

</head>




    <body>


<!--------------------------Header of the Page----------------------->
<div id="boxcolor">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Occulture</h1>
            <p class="Phead">Sign up to learn more! <br> <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/></p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <!--------------------------Header of the Page----------------------->

<p>This is a simple test Paragraph to see if this will inherit the body tag elements </p>
```

Comment: Please share both your HTML and CSS as code in the question itself (not as a picture). Without the HTML, we can't determine which elements are being targetted.

Comment: Please Shulkin, add a code snippet [reprex] which includes the specific html too. For now, the generic approach is `body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`, some container (or black box) inside `<body>` with T/R/B/L spacing `container: { ...padding: 10px; ...}` and put elements inside that container (or black box). Really CSS 101. Also, don't think 'inheritance', but in terms of moving pieces of text (content, graphics) around the screen.

Comment: Furthermore: elements with `margin>0` will take up `margin` space extra from their parent element (essentially become larger), while elements with `padding>0` will take away `padding` space from their child elements (stay the same size, but have less room to spare). Make sure you learn to understand the difference. Also some **mandatory** reading [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

From your question I get the impression that you think there is some 'OO' (object oriented) logic attached to HTML and CSS. This is NOT the case. Admitted, child elements can 'inherit' from their parents, but only when specifically assigning the `inherit` value to their attributes like `.someSelector { background-color: inherit }`. That would be the only reference to 'OOP' you can make. Lose the thought, completely.

Mandatory reading [w3school: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Get a good understanding of CSS classes, selectors and selector specifity, why they are used, when and how they are used. Html knowledge includes the meaning of parent-child nesting constructions and sibling element constructions.

In your case you would need two distinct **sibling** containers inside your document **parent** container: `<body>`.

- a `.header` **parent** container (black background) with 10px inner space, containing `h1` and `p` **child** elements
- a `.content` **parent** container (white background) with 10px inner space, containing a `p` **child** element

To fully align both containers to the document sides, you first need to lose the html default `<body>` margin of 8px: `body { margin: 0 }`

Then create two containers inside `<body>` (header and content) and assign spacing and colors, like below snippet.

Friendly advice, do NOT change an elements' `display` attribute if you don't know how to use it (concluded from your double `display` assignment in `body {...}`). Flexbox layout is great, when you know what it is about. Html default of `display: flex` is `row` oriented, you needed `column` oriented FBL.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sheepman, serif;
  /* font-weight: 400; /* html default */
  /* font-style: normal; /* html default */
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* never again use PX (search online "MDN units")*/
  padding: 0.625rem /* rem is px-value/16 => 10px/16 */
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.125rem /* 50px/16 */
}

.content {
  /* already has html default colors black on white */
  padding: 0.625rem /* 10px/16 */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Occulture</h1>
  <p class="Phead">Sign up to learn more! <br> <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>This is a simple test Paragraph to see if this will inherit the body tag elements </p>
</div>
```